# Using Get-AzMetric from PowerShell to get "Request count" metrics from Azure Front Door and CDN profiles service returns error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have a fairly simple requirement. I am trying to use the Get-AzMetric cmdlet for PowerShell to extract "Request Count" with aggregation "SUM" metrics for an Azure Classic Cloud service. (This is same information shows in the portal under resource group --> Front Door and CDN profiles --> Monitoring -> Metrics.)

My script as below:

Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/******" -MetricName "Request Count" -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -DetailedOutput

Error Message:-

```
Get-AzMetric : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status 
code 'BadRequest'
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.MetricsOperations.<ListWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

Even I have tried to get the result with below frontdoor cdn profile but getting an access error
(With the same reader role I am able to get result via GUI)

Get-AzFrontDoorCdnProfileResourceUsage -ResourceGroupName ***** -ProfileName ****-**-***

Error:-
Get-AzFrontDoorCdnProfileResourceUsage : The client '**@**.net' with object id '*******' does not have authorization to perform
action 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/usages/action' over scope

Please help me to resolve this script error to get the output of metrics (Request count) with Aggregation SUM.

My scripts as below:

1.
Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/******" -MetricName "Request Count" -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -DetailedOutput

2.
Get-AzFrontDoorCdnProfileResourceUsage -ResourceGroupName ***** -ProfileName ****-**-***

Comment: You need a DefaultProfile parameter.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cdn/get-azfrontdoorcdnprofileresourceusage?view=azps-9.1.0#parameters

Comment: I tried this as well however getting below access error. If I get the result in the GUI with same role then I should get the same result using powershell script as well. but here it shows access error.

Get-AzFrontDoorCdnProfileResourceUsage : The client 'xyz@**.net' with object id '******' does not have authorization to perform 
action 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/usages/action' over scope 
'/subscriptions/*****/resourceGroups/*****/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/*****' or the scope is invalid.

Comment: The credentials (DefaultProfile) has to be allow access to the data you are querying.

Comment: I have reader role for my subscription through which I am able to get the Metric data (& download excel) of my frondoor and cdn profile. Does powershell AZ modules needs another role to execute on azure ?
I mean as per my understanding if I can see the results in GUI with same reader role then I should get via powershell as well.

Comment: Not sure.  Azure need to use the same Password Server so user account is recognized.  You can check the Event Viewer on AZURE to get more details on error.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the same error as mentioned***

> ***`Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/XXXX" -MetricName "Request Count" -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -DetailedOutput`***

[image]

To resolve this issue I have followed the below steps
To get the azure metrics from front door I have used the below command

> ***`Get-AzFrontDoorCdnProfileResourceUsage -ResourceGroupName XXXXX -ProfileName XXXXX`***

[image]

To get the metrics from azure Front Door and CDN profiles using Get-AzMetric using PowerShell I have used the below command and i am able to get the desired output

> ***`Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourcegroups/Networking-Resources/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/XXXXX" -MetricName "RequestCount" -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -DetailedOutput`***

[image]

*Note:*
While writing the script please make sure that metric name should be "***RequestCount***" instead of "***request count***"